# My app keeps showing today's date and not what is in the cell I called for

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting the output of the first date of the column date where "exp" should be.  Column 3 is all expiration dates but when I call and output it It shows as a long formatted day date and time.  I know very little if anything about coding.  Please help.

This is what the output should look like except the date should be the date from the from not the top date from sheet.

MJC-AP-200 Watchguard model : AP 200is due in 10 days 09/30/17.

DMA-AP-300-2 Watchguard model : AP 300is due in 0 days 09/30/17.

Elwood Properties Watchguard model : WGD-WG026583is due in 0 days 09/30/17.

Elwood Prop-XTM-26W Watchguard model : XTM 26-Wis due in 0 days 09/30/17.

```
  function checkReminder() {
// get the spreadsheet object
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// set the first sheet as active
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
// fetch this sheet
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

// figure out what the last row is
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

// the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row
// is the headers, so start with row 2
var startRow = 2;

// grab column 8 (the 'days left' column) 
var range = sheet.getRange(2,8,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
var days_left_values = range.getValues();

// Now, grab the name column
range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var reminder_info_values = range.getValues();

// Now, grab the exp date column
range = sheet.getRange(2, 3, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var exp = range.getValue();
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
var exp = Utilities.formatDate(exp, "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yy")

// Now, grab the model column
range = sheet.getRange(2, 4, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var model = range.getValues();

var warning_count = 0;
var msg = "";

// Loop over the days left values
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var days_left = days_left_values[i][0];
if(days_left <= 60) {
  // if it's less than 60 days until due date.
  var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];

  msg = msg + ""+reminder_name+" Watchguard model : " +model[i][0]+"is due 
  in "+days_left+" days "+Utilities.formatDate(exp[i]
  [0],"GMT+1","MM/dd/yy")+".\n \n";
  warning_count++;
  }
  }

  if(warning_count) {
   MailApp.sendEmail("James@mccnet.com", 
    "Watchguard Expiration List", msg);
   }


   };
```

Answer (score 1):

By a quick look it seems that you are giving the formatDate method `new Date()` as the first parameter which actually returns today's date. I think the way you wanted it is this

```
var exp = Utilities.formatDate(exp,"GMT+1","MM/dd/yy")
```

This actually gives formatDate the date you fetched from the spreadsheet and the proper day will be formatted.

Try this code instead:

```
function checkReminder() {
// get the spreadsheet object
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// set the first sheet as active
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
// fetch this sheet
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

// figure out what the last row is
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

// the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row
// is the headers, so start with row 2
var startRow = 2;

// grab column 8 (the 'days left' column) 
var range = sheet.getRange(2,8,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
var days_left_values = range.getValues();

// Now, grab the name column
range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var reminder_info_values = range.getValues();

// Now, grab the exp date column
range = sheet.getRange(2, 3, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var exp = range.getValues();
var numRows = range.getNumRows();

// Now, grab the model column
range = sheet.getRange(2, 4, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var model = range.getValues();

var warning_count = 0;
var msg = "";

// Loop over the days left values
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var days_left = days_left_values[i][0];
if(days_left <= 60) {
  // if it's less than 60 days until due date.
  var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];

  msg = msg + ""+reminder_name+" Watchguard model : " +model[i][0]+"is due 
  in "+days_left+" days "+Utilities.formatDate(exp[i]
  [0],"GMT+1","MM/dd/yy")+".\n \n";
  warning_count++;
  }
  }

  if(warning_count) {
   MailApp.sendEmail("James@mccnet.com", 
    "Watchguard Expiration List", msg);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you that works for the first date, but it restates the first date in the list all the way down.  I knew that part was something simple I just didn't get the syntax.

Comment: Ok so you are calling the getValue to set the exp variable. That only returns the top left cell of the range. You should rather use the getValues() method to set the values for exp. This returns the values of the range in a two dimensional array. You can then access the date of let's say 3rd row by calling exp[2][0](indexes start from 0).

Comment: Now when it comes to the formatting part you can either format all of the values in exp in a loop one by one after giving exp the value of getValues. This can be done by creating another variable where you save the formatted dates in a one dimensional array. Let's call this array expFormatted for the time. Then in the end instead of outputting exp output expFormatted[i].

Comment: The other option is to in the end instead of outputting exp outputting Utilities.formatDate(exp[i][0],"GMT+1","MM/dd/yy"). I think i would go with the second method since then i don't have to do an extra loop through the dates and save them in an additional array. Hope this helps and feel free to ask anything if something's not clear.

Comment: I tried putting the  Utilities.formatDate(exp[i][0],"GMT+1","MM/dd/yy") instead of "+exp+" and I get a missing ; before statement

Comment: Did you surround the function call with + signs? Like this "+ Utilites.formatDate... +"

Comment: yes i get cannot find method formatDate(string,string,string)

Comment: Could you edit the question and put you current code as a whole there?

Comment: I edited my answer. Try the code there and tell me what happens.

Comment: I get "unterminated string literal(line 44, file "Code"

Comment: I changed the msg to fit on one line and I get cannot find method formatDate(string, string, string)   msg = msg + ""+reminder_name+" Watchguard model : " +model[i][0]+"is due in "+days_left+" days on "+Utilities.formatDate(exp[i][0],"GMT+1","MM/dd/yy")+".\n \n";

Comment: Can you log the value of exp (Logger.log(exp) and then Ctrl+Enter after the code has ran) before the loop and post the value here in the comments? Because for me it works with this code

Comment: I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Add this to the line before the loop: Logger.log(exp);
Then run the program. When it's finishdd, press Ctrl+Enter and copy the text there and paste it here.

Comment: I get a mess of date and times                   [17-09-20 15:53:34:456 PDT] [[Sat Sep 30 00:00:00 GMT-07:00 2017], [Sat Dec 09 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2017], [Thu Jan 18 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2018], [Mon Feb 26 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2018], [Mon Feb 26 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2018], [Fri May 18 00:00:00 GMT-07:00 2018], [Thu May 31 00:00:00 GMT-07:00 2018],

Comment: Seems about right. Does the output continue after that?

Comment: yes, it goes pretty far.  that's why I was just trying to truncate it to just show the date.

Comment: Can you just copy paste the end of the output here?

Comment: I took off the [i][0] and the logging result is [17-09-22 16:34:24:145 PDT] 09/30/17  but it in the email it just shows the 9/30/17 but that remains the same all the way down the email whereas the dates change on each row.

Comment: Yeah the logs seemed right when you first posted them but I think there might be something in the end of the logs that could solve the problem here. So could you paste the end of the original logs here?

Comment: I got it to run adding another semicolon at the end of the msg however I am getting the same first date as before the log now states [17-09-25 15:32:35:966 PDT] 09/30/17